# Using vlc to send m2ts file over rtsp removes metadata, looking for way to fix this?

Tags: vlc, rtsp, mpeg2-ts

(On windows) I was looking to send a m2ts (MPEG-2-ts) file, streaming using rtsp. An example of my input is below:

```
vlc sample.m2ts --sout="#rtp{sdp=rtsp://127.0.0.1:1234/stream}"
```

I am streaming to WinTAK. The video shows up and constantly loops but the metadata within the m2ts file is not there.

Is there any solution to the problem using vlc to allow metadata not to be lost so I can see it on WinTAK?